# Highcharts Angular Error 15 despite correctly ordered values

Tags: angular, highcharts

Creating a line chart in angular with `[OneToOne]=true` I am getting [Error 15](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15/).

But my data is clearly sorted in ascending order by date.

When using `[OneToOne]=false` my data shows up correctly, but only the first time loading it, loading it again, will again result in Error 15.

See example at stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ke5ocu

Comment: Hi @FuzzyTemper, Your data is not sorted. Please check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-worker-4eyf9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data doesn't appear to be sorted in the plot.

Here is a zoomed-in image using your raw data

[image: unsorted plot]

Here is a zoomed-in image after sorting and without the error

[image: sorted plot]

Here is the function I used to sort

```js
onDataReceived() {
  let chartData = dummy.pressure.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);  // <-- sort x-axis here
  this.chartOptions.series = [{
    yAxis: 0,
    name: 'Pressure',
    data: chartData,
    type: 'line',
  }];
  this.updateFlag = true;
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwgz6f).